# Updating rendered information from a json file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, file

Well, here's the thing. I've constructing a Json Data Manager, which lets me edit, update, delete and that sort of things.

I'm calling the json file this way:

```
 function readJson(jsonName){

var json = (function () {
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'myfile.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
            console.log("This is the file", json);
        }
    });
return json;
})();
```

And it actually brings the info, but not the updated info. If I change something via the manager it does the upgrading, I can check it directly looking at the file, but this variable is showing me old data, so when I render it into the view it looks the same, like nothing's changed.

Any ideas? Is there anything getting cached or something of the sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible your server is caching the response. A fairly easy approach is to "cache-bust" it by appending a random query parameter to the end of the URL. `Date.now()` is a very good option as its time-based, so it'll always be unique:

```
'url': 'myfile.json?' + Date.now()
```